# No server explorer in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, server-explorer

I've installed visual studio 2010 express in windows 7 ultimate. Now I am willing to write a visual basic program for database connection but I am not finding the server explorer window on my visual basic ide. It does contain toolbox window, data source window, properties window, solution explorer window but server explorer is not available. I checked in view menu also but it was not available there too. One thing I want to tell you is I've installed windows in VMware. Is that the problem for server explorer window or something else. I'm very new to visual basic programming, so any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you running Visual Studio 2010 rather than 2013?

Comment: I'm very new to it and don't have any experience with it and also the same version is being used in my college for which I'm learning it.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2010 Express are you using?

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem with the ide not comprising server explorer window and no sql server database connection.

Comment: I don't know. can you tell me where can I find it or what are visual studio 2010 express editions available.

Comment: the edition is 10.0, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd2cz7yy(v=vs.100).aspx ) states that the Servers node is not available in either the Standard nor Express editions of Visual Studio 2010.

As for the justification: Disclaimer: I am a Microsoft employee and a software engineer who has worked on Visual Studio, **however this is my personal opinion and not that of our marketing department**: Features are disabled or removed in lower SKUs because of money :) By excluding features that we believe only paying customers will want to use we can provide beginner users (such as students, etc) with free versions of the IDE without costing us lost revenue from high-end customers (e.g. enterprises) who would stop paying for premium editions of VS and switching to the Express editions.

Note that with Visual Studio 2013 we now have the Community Edition SKU which is free (as in beer) and restores many features absent from the Express Edition SKUs, but has EULA restrictions on its use by larger organisations. Check it out here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

> Here’s how Visual Studio Community can be used in organizations:
>
> - An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.
> - For all other usage scenarios: In non-enterprise organizations, up to 5 users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or > $1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.